# Mule - Which code snippet would you recommend for FunctionalTestCase, and what are their differences?

Tags: mule

I come across two seemingly similar yet different variations of codes for Functional Testing. Which is the recommended one and what are their differences?

=== Snippet 1 ===

```
@Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        return "src\\main\\app\\simplejunittest.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void testHelloWorldFlow2Returns2() throws Exception
    {
        runFlowWithPayloadAndExpect("simplejunittestFlow1", "someTextxxxx", "Pass");
    }


    ///////////////////////////// HELPERS ////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
    * Run the flow specified by name using the specified payload and assert
    * equality on the expected output
    *
    * @param flowName The name of the flow to run
    * @param expect The expected output
    * @param payload The payload of the input event
    */
    protected <U, T> void runFlowWithPayloadAndExpect(String flowName, U payload, T expect) throws Exception
    {
        Flow flow = lookupFlowConstruct(flowName);
        MuleEvent event = FunctionalTestCase.getTestEvent(payload);
        MuleEvent responseEvent = flow.process(event);

        assertEquals(expect, responseEvent.getMessage().getPayload());
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a flow by name from the registry
     *
     * @param name Name of the flow to retrieve
     */
    protected Flow lookupFlowConstruct(String name)
    {
        return (Flow) FunctionalTestCase.muleContext.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct(name);
    }
```

=== Snippet 2 ===

```
@Override
protected String getConfigResources() {
    return "./src/main/app/simplejunittest.xml";
}

@Test
public void testClient2PersonMigration() throws Exception {
    MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
    String payload = "someTextxxxx";
    Map<String, Object> messageProperties = null;
    MuleMessage result = client.send("http://localhost:8081/", payload, messageProperties); //URL, Payload, MessageProperties

    assertNotNull(result);
    assertNull(result.getExceptionPayload());
    assertFalse(result.getPayload() instanceof NullPayload);
    assertEquals("Pass", result.getPayloadAsString()); //if I comment this it works
}
```

=== Configuration XML of Snippet 1 & 2 ===

```
<flow name="simplejunittestFlow1" doc:name="simplejunittestFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#['Fail']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <flow-ref name="simplejunittestFlow2" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="simplejunittestFlow2" doc:name="simplejunittestFlow2">
    <set-payload value="#['Pass']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</sub-flow>
```

**Question:** Is there a recommended one between Snippet 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big difference is that in snippet 1 you send a message that does not represent the actual message that will hit your service, as what's done in snippet 2. Indeed, you're missing all the inbound message properties that are set by the HTTP transport. Also you use a `String` payload instead of an `InputStream` one, as the HTTP transport does.

Therefore, I strongly suggest using snippet 2 to have the most realistic test conditions. BTW in Snippet 2, you'd rather use a generic HTTP Client to ensure that the service is working fine for non-Mule clients as well. Also you should use the dynamic port feature instead of hard-coding `8081` to avoid collisions when running tests.

I would reserve snippet 1 to private flows or flows with an inbound endpoint type that doesn't have any natural inbound properties, like VM.

Comment: How to use or setup (1) dynamic port feature instead of hard-coding 8081? (2) generic HTTP Client?

Comment: This test case illustrates both 1) and 2) https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.1/transports/http/src/test/java/org/mule/transport/http/functional/HttpMethodTestCase.java

Answer (score 1):

In Snippet1 you run the flow directly with some payload, and in Snippet2 you send the payload to the inbound endpoint of the flow. So, the difference is that the inbound endpoint is ignored in Snippet1, and you can use this approach if you do not need to test the endpoint.